# How does Spotify posts playlists onto Facebook wall via API?

Tags: facebook, spotify, facebook-wall

It seems that Facebook API only allows text, image, video and flash embeds to be posted onto users' walls via API, but somehow Spotify posts these complex playlists with play buttons, images, etc.

How do they do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the new Open Graph APIs announced at this year's [F8](http://f8.facebook.com/) Conference and (as of now, 2011-10-05 is in testing only)

The documentation is linked from the front page of the [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) site so you can start building against these APIs now for test purposes

Comment: Hi Igy, I was unable to discern instructions on creating play list posts from the given link.